# Dynamic values for workspace, dataset and table when adding row to a Power BI data set

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I am using the 'Add rows to a dataset' to Power BI connector which should point to different streaming datasets.

I would like to fill out the workspace, dataset and table values dynamically. Is this possible?

I've included an image of the connector I am working with. So far I have tried initializing a string variable with UUID's but that doesn't work.

EDIT: Added image of error when I try to add workspace as a dynamic value

[image: Add rows to a dataset connector]
[image: ErrorMsg]

Comment: Which part doesn't work?  It fails in the LogicApp or succeeds in the LogicApp but nothing appears in the streaming dataset?

Comment: Added image, its unable to find the values in the dataset

Comment: Oh wow, I don't have any of those additional options relating to the min and max values.  That actually looks to be part of your problem though.  Have you specified things that are not permitted?  If you take them out, does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work so to make sure you're doing the right thing, you need to do something like the following.

First of all, create your string variable that store the workspace name, GUID of the DataSet and the name of the table ...

[image: Variables]

If you want to be sure of the names, etc. then do it using the dropdowns and then look at the code view to get the right values ...

[image: Code View]

Now to assign the variables, make sure you select the following option ...

[image: Dropdown]

... now you can select your variables.

If you're going to make the thing dynamic, you need to pass in a `Body` that has a serialized `Payload`.  It looks different to the connector when you're using the dropdowns to select your workspace, dataset and table.

This is an example of the payload (must be an array) ...

```
[ { "DateTime": "2022-03-25T12:32:20.063Z", "Value": 120 } ]
```

... and as you can see from the below, the `Body` needs to have a single property called `Payload` and that will contain the serialized JSON.

[image: PowerBi]

When I do all of that, it works ...

[image: Result]

[image: Result]